# CUDA tgamma function: is documentation wrong or tgamma isn't a gamma?

Tags: math, cuda

According to [CUDA doumentation of tgamma](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g5ca5ecfde03d152d1bdd3fd29bf88c7c) this function calculates the Gamma function and has this properties, among others:

```
tgamma(2) returns +0.
tgamma(x) returns NaN if x < 0.
```

But this is different from the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) we all know. Thus the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a bug of the document. You could refer to `std::tgamma` and `std::lgamma` for comparison.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/lgamma

> tgamma(2) returns +0.

This looks like `lgamma`.

> tgamma(x) returns NaN if x < 0.

This looks like they wanted to say x is negative integer.

You could writing some code to compare.

Comment: I think you are right, probably a copy-paste bug in the docs.

Comment: @Michael I would suggest reporting this documentation bug to NVIDIA, using the bug reporting form linked from the CUDA registered developer web page.